# Find the next input value from a table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some table data with some codes:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' class='ACode' value='3400' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' class='DCode' value='100' /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' class='ACode' value='3000' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' class='DCode' value='130' /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' class='ACode' value='2500' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' class='DCode' value='110' /></td>
<tr>
```

When I want to access the `ACode` next input value using jQuery like this:

```
$('.ACode').change(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  var DCode =  that.next('.DCode').val();
});
```

it doesn't show the value.

Comment: Thank you Jonsca for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
var DCode =  that.parent().next().find('.DCode').val();
```

`.ACode` does *not* have siblings, thus [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) does not get anything, since it only returns the immediately following siblings. Instead, you should go to the parent `td`, which indeed has one sibling, use `.next()` to get to the next `td`, and then find `.DCode`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LGh6y/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.ACode').change(function(){
    var that = $(this),
        DCode =  that.closest('tr').find('.DCode').val();
});
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: thank you David i was trying this for last couple hours. using some other jQuery index method but couldn't find the correct solution. you helped me.